# WPF Set label background to image depending on content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, triggers

I have the following Xaml code and I have label triggers. I want to have a trigger that will place an image in the background for some content value. How do i do this as a trigger?

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2">
        <Label Content="{Binding }" Width="70" Height="70" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" x:Name="Background">
        </Label>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="1">
                <Setter TargetName="Background" Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="5">
                <Setter TargetName="Background" Property="Background" Value="Image"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding }" Value="9">
                <Setter TargetName="Background" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="7">
                <Setter TargetName="Background" Property="Background" Value="blue"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level2}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Do you want to set `Image` to `Background` of `Label`?

Comment: Yes, but only if the label has a certain value, as in it needs to be like a trigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use ImageBrush as background.

First add the brush in the resources.
Example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="MyImageBrush"
                ImageSource="C:\Test.png" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Then simply use StaticResource to set it in the specific trigger.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2">
        <Label Content="{Binding }"
               Width="70"
               Height="70"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
               x:Name="Background">
        </Label>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}"
                         Value="7">
                <Setter TargetName="Background"
                        Property="Background"
                        Value="{StaticResource MyImageBrush}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```